# Adding files to git index without committing

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, tortoisegit

When using Git, my workflow usually involves firing up TortoiseGit and selecting the files that i'd like to commit.

This (i assume) runs *git add* (?) and commits these changes to the local repo.

My question is -- why is the separation between ADDING files to the index and COMMITTING them needed?

Are there any use cases for simply adding files to the index without committing them at the same moment?

Answer (score 8):

Adding files to the index is called staging. Staging provides a separation between what is to be committed and what is to remain outside the commit. If you made some changes that are better suited for a different commit, you can just leave them there without staging and make a commit for things that were added to the index.

So, in essence, it helps you prepare simple, coherent commits.

Answer (score 3):

I use the index/staging area quite a bit. It can be thought of a little bit like a shopping cart. It lets you wander around your project, adding things as you go, filling up your cart. Once you have what you want, you commit (i.e. buy those changes and leave the store).

One great feature of this is patch-adding. `git add -p` aka `git add --patch` lets you choose particular hunks from a file, so you can actually commit parts of various files. I do this every day, though I use the pathogen plugin for Vim, which makes it very easy and visual to hop around from change to change, moving them back and forth between the working copy and the index copy. Once I have only the parts of a nice, granular commit added to the cart, I commit it with a sensible, granular commit message, 50 characters or fewer. This has made my history incredible to reason about, and it's let me change my mind an hour later and interactively rebase to push commits together, and reorder them into a more sensible flow, sometimes to get unit tests working at each commit, so I have clean, safe, rollback points everywhere in my history.

I've also used patch adding to help me figure out which parts of a file make sense together. In Vim I do `,gs`, which in a new split window pops open a git status for the repo of the current file. I use `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` to hop around the lines of the status message with actual files on them. I use `D` on those lines to vimdiff them in a set of split windows, then `]c` and `c[` top hop from change to change, using `dp` (diff put) and `do` (diff obtain) to move changes to or from the current buffer (these work from either split, and `<C-w>h` and `<C-w>l` hop me back and forth between buffers). Once I like what I've staged for that file, I `:w` to save it, and `<C-w>k` up to the status split again to either choose a new file to stage in this way, or to `-` on files in either set to toggle them into and out of staging entirely, or to `cc` to actually commit, whereupon it asks for a commit message. I can review all the things going in through these means before committing to the commit, and often I'll realize at this point that I forgot something, or added something I shouldn't, and correct it. My commits are thus rather pristine. If I want to `commit --amend`, I can stage things and use `cA` instead of `cc`, or `ca` if I also want to reword the commit message.

In short, committing whole files - as I used to do in my SVN days - feels very coarse and incorrect to me now. It's really hard to change only one concern while working, but patch-adding through the power of the index let's me tease out the actual changes that make sense together in one commit.

Answer (score 1):

Staging is almost like a mini-commit for a file. You can stage, re-stage, view the changes as if you committed, and even revert to the most recent stage - before actually committing. Doing several mini-commits can aid you in organization, just as doing several full commits can.

It's a finer level of granularity, essentially.

Also it lets you toy around a bit locally before committing - it's effectively the same as creating a playground branch and doing a bunch of commits, then merging back in before the final commit. Just a lot more lightweight than all that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to commit all files you added to the index/staging area.

```
git add fileA
git add fileB
git add fileC
```

Use case 1: commit only fileA and fileB:

```
git commit -m "fileA, fileB added." fileA fileB
```

Use case 2: tracking changes of files after adding them to the staging area. This will show you the difference between working-copy and the last time you added the file to the staging area.

Answer (score -1):

In SmartGit you can click right mouse btn on file, and select satge.